# What is the Python coding standard for class methods on classes that will never be instantiated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-3.8

I am reading a book where they use a Python class as a container to bundle several functions in a group. The class will never be instantiated. For the methods in this class, there is no `cls` or `self` parameter (this confused me). Since I am familiar with classes (that will/might be instantiated) and `@classmethods`, I am wondering if there is a name and a PEP guideline for these kind of classes that will never be instantiated?

The same name spacing could be achieved by putting those methods in different files instead of a class. But there might be a good reason to prefer a class for this purpose?

In the example below, you can see that the methods 'addition' and 'addition_2' behave similar, except when the class will be instantiated (of course).
So it seems that you don't need the `@classmethod` and `cls` parameter in the case where you will **never** instantiate that class. But is that good practice?

```
# python 3.8.5
class Operations:

    @classmethod
    def addition(cls, value, value_2):
        print(value + value_2)

    def addition_2(value, value_2):
        print(value + value_2)


Operations.addition(value=3, value_2=5)  # 8
Operations.addition(3, 5)  # 8
Operations().addition(value=3, value_2=5)  # 8
Operations().addition(3, 5)  # 8

Operations.addition_2(value=3, value_2=5)  # 8
Operations.addition_2(3, 5)  # 8

# expected errors:
Operations().addition_2(value=3, value_2=5)  # TypeError: addition_2() got multiple values for argument 'value'
Operations().addition_2(3, 5)  # TypeError: addition_2() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: *"where they use a Python class as a container to bundle several functions"* That's more a Java thing, not needed (but possible) in Python. A module is fine to bundle functions.

Comment: Ya, that's not really a good practice. I can't see any benefit to grouping in a class vs grouping in a module.

Comment: Fair enough. 
Would you say that 'addition_2' (a normal method without cls or self parameter) in my example is only good practice if it is called by other methods in **the same** class, and nowhere else (since it is defined in this scope).
And that for all cases where you want to access this method from somewhere else, it should be a static method instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a class which will never be instantiated and is simply a container for functions:

```
class Operations:

    @staticmethod
    def addition(value, value_2):
        print(value + value_2)

    @staticmethod
    def subtraction(value, value_2):
        print(value + value_2)
```

However as others have said this is not really best practice and you can just have these functions stored in a different module instead i.e. a .py file called operations which you use by importing it:

```
import operations

operations.addition(1, 2)
```